# Don't include header on first page (CFPDF + DDX)

Tags: coldfusion, cfpdf, ddx

I'm using DDX to add headers, footers, and pagination to PDF documents. If possible I would like the header for the *first* page of each file to be blank, but then to have headers for the remaining pages.

I've looked through the documentation and can't find a way to do this. It seems like a commonly used feature so I'm guessing there must be some way to implement it.

Comment: The closest I see is the [`alternation` attribute](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/ddxRef/001070.html), which does not quite do what you need. If all else fails, what about applying the header to pages `2-N` then merging it back with page `1`? A hack to be sure, but might do the trick. (Edit) Also, have you tried using [`<cfpdf action="addheader">`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html)? I *think* it supports a page number range.

Comment: How would I apply the header to only specific pages? Are you talking about splitting up the PDF and then merging it again?

Comment: (Edit) Yep. If it does not support page ranges for headers (which seems to be the case), you need a split + merge work-around. You might be able to achieve the same affect by using multiple `<PDF>` tags: one for the first page and another for pages `2-N`, with a nested header tag ie `<PDF pages="1">...</PDF><PDF pages="2-N"><Header...></PDF>`

Comment: @Leigh, using multiple `<PDF src="..." pages="...">` is the answer; so please go ahead and post it as an answer instead of a comment so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments)

You might be able to achieve this effect by using multiple [`<PDF>`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/ddxRef/001125.html) tags: one for the first page and another for pages `2-N`, with a nested [`<Header>`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/ddxRef/001070.html) tag.

ie :

```
 <PDF pages="1" src="c:/path/someFile.pdf">
 ...
 </PDF>
 <PDF pages="2-last" src="c:/path/someFile.pdf">
    <Header...>
 </PDF>
```

Comment: This is how I did it; worked perfectly. Instead of `2-N`, just use `2-last`.